# How to optimize Linux Mint performance

Tags: linux, laptop, performance, linux-mint, performance-tuning

I'm running Linux Mint 14 on notebook. This notebook is rather old and really weak. Linux Mint shows better performance than Win7, but newertheless it's far from perfect. What can I do to speed up my OS?

Comment: I'd say install xubuntu. If it's old and it's a notebook, I guess its specs are far from great. Optimising OS is much harder than using dedicated one.

Comment: Are you using cinnamon or mate as your DE, try using mate, (you can install it using software manager)

Comment: I'm not the main user of this laptop. It's owner was a Windows user, so it's quite easy for him to use Cinnamon DE. That's why it's not the best choice to use another DE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through and disable any services you don't need.  I suggest checking out the Linux Mint forums for help on that.  I don't know your level of Linux expertise.

For example, if you don't have any bluetooth devices, disable anything bluetooth.